# Can I remove the Install OS X Yosemite app?

Tags: macos, applications

I'm trying to free up some space on my MacBook and I found this in the Applications folder.

[image: Applications in Finder]

Can I delete it? I'm a iOS developer and I don't want issues.

Currently I'm running OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are safe to delete the Yosemite installer. It should not harm your computer if you delete it.